# Why my overload operator+ in this c++ class doesn't need to be implemented as operator-?

Tags: c++, class

```
friend complex operator +(complex &t1, complex &t2);

complex operator-(complex &t){
    complex tmp(this->a - t.a, this->b - t.b);
    return tmp;
}
```

I'm learning c++. I don't understand why operator+ don't need to be written as operator-?

Comment: These are declaration and definition of 2 different overloaded operators.

Comment: A variety of operators (unary and binary `+` and `-` included) can be either overloaded in class (as member function) or as free-standing function with the class as arguments (and possibly made `friend` to allow access to `private` members). I somewhere read the latter should be preferred but both ways are legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both achieve the same goal. In the first case, the global `operator+` function is made `friend` of this class so it can access private members. The second overloaded `operator-` is automatically called when '-' is used between two `complex` objects.